# Unable to extend volume on Suse VM

Tags: linux, opensuse

I have a SUSE VM (11.4) that I increased the disk for. I am following the guide (http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/extending-partitions-on-linux-vmware-virtual-machines/). This added sda3.

I got to *vgextend [volume group] /dev/sdaX*, *vgextend rootfs /dev/sda3*

But it says no volume group found. When I run fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 220.1 GB, 220117073920 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26761 cylinders, total 429916160 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x32fa04e4

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   209715199   104857568+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2       209715200   220200959     5242880   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       220200960   429916159   104857600   83  Linux
```

and df -h:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                 99G   93G  1.4G  99% /
devtmpfs             1001M  104K 1001M   1% /dev
tmpfs                1004M  4.0K 1004M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1              99G   93G  1.4G  99% /
```

I also ran *vgdisplay* which says "No volume groups found".

Comment: You're not using LVM!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And that's why you don't blindly following tutorials without knowing what they are talking about.

Your installation doesn't use LVM so you can't extend the size of the disks by a method meant to increase LVM volume size.